# Modify Several Plist Using a Script

Tags: mac, bash, unix

defaults read /New.plist itemName

the Output Will Be Some Thing Like "Software"
but i want the new Data to be updated for the key as "Software Old Version"
the problem is i have to modify several plists

defaults read /New.plist itemName "Software Old Version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop or find:

`for f in /path/to/first.plist /path/to/second.plist; do defaults write "$f" itemName "Software Old Version"; done`

`find /folder -name '*.plist' -exec defaults write {} itemName "Software Old Version" \;`